# Can't retrieve user's mail address from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've correclty created a `Facebook` app, placing the `email` tag in the user permission, into the `Auth Dialog` section.

The problem that I can't access to the user mail.. I don't receive this parameter as  response, I only receive: `last_name`, `firt_name`, `birthday` and other unnecessary data, I need the email..

I know that it's possible if the user accept the auth dialog conditions, but for what reason I can't retrieve it?

Comment: How about you paste some code of what you've already tried so we can see what's not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `email` permission has been granted (a call to /me/permissions will verify this), a call to `/me/?fields=email` should produce the user's email address.

If that's not happening you'll need to be more clear about what the problem is.

Comment: I've done some proof... in  the preview of  the auth dialog, i see that the application have access to basic information and "user email address"... BUT when i effectively try to launch the app, auth dialog don't report the email address (only basic info). 
Then seems that there are a problem with configuration of the app..
I've just gone into Auth Dialog Advanced ---> User & Friend Permissions ---> added "email" tag and saved all
What i wrong?

Comment: The Auth Dialog settings for App Center and Authenticated Referrals are independent from the settings on dialogs you manually redirect users to (i.e those users that land on your website or app without going through the app center) - see the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation for more information  (Abhishek's answer has the right code for PHP, but you really should read the entire document)

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem. We had all required permission on the auth dialog permissions setting. but it will not show up when really use the app.

We used the scope to fix it. 
Try this

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope'=>'{permission that your app require}'));
```

For example

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope'=>'email,read_friendlists'));
```

by addig scope varible the auth dialog will ask for these permission.
May be this will help you.